# Алфавитная навигация в Django

Tags: python, django

Коллеги, пробую сделать на сайте алфавитную навигацию в онлайн словаре. По идее, при клике на определенную букву должны выводиться слова, которые начинаются с нее.
По сути алфавитная навигация, это те же категории.
Вот как выглядит код в `models.py`:

```
class Alphabet(models.Model):
    harf = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Letter')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.harf


class Words(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Word')
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio', blank=True, verbose_name='Sound')
    russian = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='Russian')
    english = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='English')
    turkish = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='Turkish')
    letter = models.ForeignKey(Alphabet, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Letter')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Word'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Words'
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при клике на одну букву, в этой букве отображаются все слова, которые есть в базе. Вот так выглядит views.py:

```
def letter(request, letter_id):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    word = Words.objects.filter().order_by('title')
    showletter = get_object_or_404(Words, id=letter_id)
    paginator = Paginator(word, 3)
    word = paginator.page(page)
    return render(request, 'myapp/letter.html', {'showletter': showletter, 'word': word})
```

И скорее всего проблема, тут. Долго бился, но ничего не выходит, видимо сказывается мой небольшой опыт, не так уж давно начал изучать Python/Django, поэтому прошу вашей помощи, коллеги.

Template:

```
{% for words in word %}
        <li class="listofwords"><a class="foundword" href="{% url 'translations' words.id %}">{{ words.title }}</a>
            <span id="flags">
                {% if words.russian %}<img class="countryflags" src="{% static 'images/RU.png' %}" alt="RUS">{% endif %}
                {% if words.english %}<img class="countryflags" src="{% static 'images/GB.png' %}" alt="ENG">{% endif %}
                {% if words.turkish %}<img class="countryflags" src="{% static 'images/TR.png' %}" alt="TUR">{% endif %}
            </span>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `word = Words.objects.filter().order_by('title')` - это все слова, которые есть в базе. Их вы в шаблон и выводите, никак не фильтруя.

Алгоритм, на мой взгляд, несколько странный. Почему не использовать `Words.objects.filter(title__istartswith=letter)`? Да и хранить в базе буквы (тем более в поле длинной 10 символов) мне кажется странным. Может лучше страницу с буквами формировать чем-нибудь вроде

```
titles = Words.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).distinct()
chars = [t[0] for t in titles]
```

Comment: такой способ отпадает, потому что специфика языка, для которого делается словарь заключается в том, что некоторые звуки в этом языке обозначаются буквосочетаниями.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev тогда просто впишите условие фильтрации
`showletter = get_object_or_404(Alphabet, id=letter_id)
word = Words.objects.filter(letter=showletter).order_by('title')`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Возникает такая ошибка:
`ValueError at /letter/1/
Cannot query "Абгъуэ": Must be "Alphabet" instance.` Возможно проблема в template, выше обновил пост.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev это странно, showletter на момент фильтрации должна быть экземпляром Alphabet или view выбросила бы http404.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev давайте попробуем убрать лишний шаг `words = get_list_or_404(Words, letter_id=int(letter_id))`

Comment: http404 выскакивает тогда, когда у "буквы" нет отнесенных к нему слов.